# A SRVE0207E error occurs with a web service on Bluemix

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, ibm-cloud

This is the runtime log of my web service on `bluemix`. When I try to call a API, it returns the following error:

> "Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet" on the page and this is the log shown.

The code works well on the other web service. But when I try to merge it into this web service, it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me which part is wrong?

```
9/9/2015 12:52:56 AM    OUT App Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 2015.8.0.0/wlp-1.0.10.20150728-1158) on IBM J9 VM, version pxa6470_27sr3fp10-20150708_01 (SR3 FP10) (en_US)
9/9/2015 12:53:19 AM    ERR App at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:332)
9/8/2015 11:58:53 PM    OUT App [INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module Hello Java has been bound to default_host.
9/9/2015 12:15:01 AM    OUT App [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [json-1.0, jpa-2.0, icap:managementConnector-1.0, beanValidation-1.0, jdbc-4.0, managedBeans-1.0, cloudAutowiring-1.0, jsf-2.0, jsp-2.2, servlet-3.0, jaxrs-1.1, jndi-1.0, appState-1.0, ejbLite-3.1, cdi-1.0].
9/9/2015 12:27:20 AM    OUT App [INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module com.ibm.ws.cloudoe.management.client.liberty.connector has been bound to default_host.
9/9/2015 12:27:39 AM    ERR App at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
9/9/2015 12:27:39 AM    ERR App at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:401)
9/9/2015 12:28:05 AM    ERR App [ERROR   ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [javax.ws.rs.core.Application] in application [myapp]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/ws/rs/core/Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
9/9/2015 12:28:12 AM    ERR App at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:332)
9/9/2015 12:33:53 AM    OUT App [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application myapp started in 1.548 seconds.
9/9/2015 12:34:30 AM    OUT App [INFO    ] SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/
9/9/2015 12:34:31 AM    ERR App at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:332)
9/9/2015 12:34:36 AM    ERR App at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
9/9/2015 12:34:36 AM    ERR App at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
9/9/2015 12:42:35 AM    OUT App [AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://18usg1n4kmq:62380/IBMMGMTRest/
9/9/2015 12:42:51 AM    ERR App at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
9/9/2015 12:42:51 AM    ERR App at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:362)
9/9/2015 12:51:57 AM    OUT STG -----> Auto-configuration is creating config for service instance 'SRTDatabase' of type 'SQLDB'
9/9/2015 12:53:17 AM    ERR App at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
9/9/2015 12:53:17 AM    ERR App at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is the NoSuchMethodError seen in the log:

> [myapp]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax/ws/rs/core/Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

This method doesn't exist in JAX-RS 1.1 which is what the Liberty server is loading:

> 9/9/2015 12:15:01 AM    OUT App [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server
>   installed the following features: [json-1.0, jpa-2.0,
>   icap:managementConnector-1.0, beanValidation-1.0, jdbc-4.0,
>   managedBeans-1.0, cloudAutowiring-1.0, jsf-2.0, jsp-2.2, servlet-3.0,
>   **jaxrs-1.1**, jndi-1.0, appState-1.0, ejbLite-3.1, cdi-1.0].

To fix this you will either need to stop using that method or push a packaged Liberty server configuration to Bluemix that contains your app and the server.xml to load the `jaxrs-2.0` feature instead of the `jaxrs-1.1` feature. Details on how to push a packaged liberty server are [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#optionsforpushinglibertyapplications).

Comment: We introduced a new feature in the Liberty buildpack which enables you to specify the features using the environment variable "JBP_CONFIG_LIBERTY" for WAR/EAR applications. This means you can still push a WAR. See the doc: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html#optionsforpushinglibertyapplications